# How would intelligent life adapt on a black hole planet?

Tags: planets, black-holes, adaptability

The world I'm building, Qi'raad, orbits a stellar-mass black hole. How would life best adapt to survive? Also, the black hole, named Halku, emits a relatively thin radio jet, which has carved a large canyon on Qi'raad's ecliptic. The planet isn't tidally locked yet.

Comment: The ecliptic is an imaginary line in the sky, corresponding to the intersection of the planet's orbital plane with the celestial sphere. How did the radio jet carve a canion on it?

Comment: It spews matter as well, which collides with the planet at high speed, knocking material into space.

Comment: The ecliptic is an imaginary line **in the sky**. Is the canyon also imaginary and in the sky?

Comment: Not the sky ecliptic, the ecliptic projected onto the surface. The planet orbits in the same plane as the radio jets.

Comment: It would be a somewhat bizarre orbit that would take a planet over the black hole's "pole" to be struck by a jet - particularly since that would plunge it _through_ the accretion disk twice every orbit.

Comment: We'll just say it somehow has a polar orbit.

Comment: @Pycoder well yes, you can do quite a bit about your planet without "science-based" tag :)

Comment: Also, an intermediate-mass black hole has an event horizon radius of ~$5\times10^6$ km.  [Radio jet diameters are expressed in multiples of the gravitational radius of the emitting body](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-018-0431-2/figures/3).  So you wouldn't be carving a canyon, you'd be obliterating the planet.

Comment: Okay, maybe just stellar-mass.

Comment: Can the adapting intelligent life be from elsewhere?  Like human refugees on this planet?  Or must the life be native?

Comment: It's native. This is my planet, I make the rules.

Comment: I'm still skeptical about that carved canyon idea.  With the `science-based` tag absent, I guess you can just make it magic, but a comparative stellar-mass black hole exhibiting a radio jet has a jet energy of [$10^{41}$ ergs](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/ab88b6/meta), or ~$10^{35}$ joules.  Given that the binding energy of Earth is about three orders of magnitude lower than that, even scaling back to a sun-mass black hole would result in delivering enough energy to liquefy the entire surface of the planet.

Comment: The projection of the ecliptic onto the planet's surface varies from day to day. For example, in the case of Earth, the projection of the ecliptic onto Earth's surface sweeps the entire area between the tropics in the course of a year: that would make for a very wide canyon... (Intuitively, that's because the Sun is by definition always on the ecliptic.)

Comment: Can you tell us anything about the planet? You can't say, "a lot like Earth!" because that would require the specific energy characteristics of Sol, meaning that the planet's relationship to the black hole is such that the characteristics of the black hole no longer matter. Unless what you're really asking is, what would be the characteristics of a planet orbiting my black hole such that the planet ended up a lot like Earth, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking.

Comment: I know it isn't like Earth, what I'm asking is how life would adapt to this planet.

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be all `science-based`.

Comment: Do you mean equator rather than ecliptic?

Comment: @AlexP The planet isn't like Earth, it has a small axial tilt and therefore small ecliptic range.

Answer (score 5):

Black hole's accretion disk burning rate is nowhere as constant as Sun-like star's, and its spectrum is not life-friendly (as @Demigan had already noticed).

Intelligent life at or little above the tech level of modern day humanity would have to dig underground and shelter there. A more advanced civilization might be able to construct some kind of planetary shield to protect itself from harmful radiation and periods of extreme luminosity.

Comment: I'm assuming that life evolved underground and learned how to use radiation shields eventually. Or, it might be just UV-resistant in the first place.

Comment: @Pycoder Evolution on such a planet would be very problematic. On Earth, it took billions of years under our very stable Sun. Black hole planet, I assume, would oscillate between the periods of "snowball" and Venus-like greenhouse, losing all of its water relatively early in its history.

Comment: @Pycoder - it's hard to imagine life (as we know it) evolving at all in an environment that hostile.

Comment: My imaginary black hole's accretion disk is relative uniformly spread out, scattering energy around.

Answer (score 3):

I'm ignoring how the planet got there in the first place or what orbit it might have.

Your life will need light and warmth to survive at all. A BH accretion disk could provide this. The time warping effects on the accretion disk apparently shifts light into higher energies causing more harmful UV radiation.

Your life forms will need more resistances to radiation and UV light at minimum. Possibly adapt to weird season cycles as the light of the accretion disk might not be as constant as you would want.

Edit: for some more information this short article might give a bit: https://news.berkeley.edu/2019/07/25/milky-ways-central-black-hole-puts-einsteins-theories-to-the-test/

It talks a bit about the ludicrous size of the black hole (more than 30x the size of our own supermassive black hole) and its spin. Also that it has to be an old galaxy so the matter feeding the accretion disk doesn't rip the atmosphere away and other such unfortunate things.

Comment: Light from near a black hole tends to be redshifted, rather than blueshifted - the emission of high-energy radiation is mostly thermal and comes from the extremely hot gas in the disk - I think it's in the range of a few million Kelvin for the objects the OP's describing. You'd also likely see x-ray emission from the inner regions, rather than just UV emission.

Comment: @HDE226868 You seem to be right. I had read it in an article that is now gone from my search history. I would then suspect that it is the x-rays redshifted to ultraviolet.

Comment: In my story, it's a rogue planet that got captured, which explains its weird orbit.